# Can't connect to appium server after started

Tags: python-3.x, appium-android

After started appium server by code:

```
service = AppiumService()
service.start(args=['--address', '127.0.0.1', '-p', str(DEFAULT_PORT), '--chromedriver-executable', 'D:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe'])
```

```
C:\Users\abc>netstat -aof | findstr :4723
  TCP    127.0.0.1:4723         abc:0               LISTENING       1660
  TCP    127.0.0.1:4723         www.techsmith.com:61607  ESTABLISHED     1660
  TCP    127.0.0.1:4723         www.techsmith.com:61616  ESTABLISHED     1660
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61607        www.techsmith.com:4723  ESTABLISHED     18636
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61616        www.techsmith.com:4723  ESTABLISHED     18636
```

Then I connect to sever by code:

```
webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', ANDROID_BASE_CAPS)
```

It hang at this command and no error log show.
I am using npm appium@1.18.0-beta.0, android 8 
Please help to unblock me here. Thanks.